# AWS Amplify: How to install sharp in Lambda Trigger?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, sharp

I am new to using **AWS Amplify** and **AWS Lambda** and
I'm facing a problem that I can't solve on my own.

**Explanation:**

I ran the command:

```
amplify add storage
```

This command generated for me the trigger below:

```
exports.handler = async function (event) {
  console.log('Received S3 event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
  console.log(`Bucket: ${bucket}`, `Key: ${key}`);
};
```

**What I want to do?**

I would like to resize the images that are uploaded to my bucket.

**What's the problem?**

My problem is that I can't install **sharp** package.

Because of yarn, I cannot run this command:

```
npm install sharp
```

With npm, I get this error (remove package-lock.json file don't resolve the problem):

> warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files
> generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package
> managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by
> unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove
> package-lock.json.

So I ran this command:

```
yarn add sharp
```

But I still have errors.
I created a video that I uploaded to Youtube:
https://youtu.be/iZANbmVhhp4

Also I tested that but it's not works:

↓ ↓ ↓

https://sahanamarsha.medium.com/resizing-s3-images-with-aws-lambda-trigger-ca4cf2372d0e

https://github.com/SahanAmarsha/image-resizer-lambda/blob/master/package.json

↑ ↑ ↑

Creating thumbnails is very common and I don't understand why I can't do it.
Can you explain to me step-by-step how to do it?
So that I can understand why I can't.

Regards

**Additional infos**

Here is the **Execution result:failed Details** I get in the AWS console:

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "\nSomething went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module\n\nCannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/Runtime.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js\n\nPossible solutions:\n- Install with verbose logging and look for errors: \"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --foreground-scripts --verbose sharp\"\n- Install for the current linux-x64 runtime: \"npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp\"\n- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install",
  "trace": [
    "Error: ",
    "Something went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module",
    "",
    "Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js",
    "- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js",
    "- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js",
    "- /var/task/index.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/Runtime.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "",
    "Possible solutions:",
    "- Install with verbose logging and look for errors: \"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --foreground-scripts --verbose sharp\"",
    "- Install for the current linux-x64 runtime: \"npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp\"",
    "- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js:34:9)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)",
    "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)",
    "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:8:1)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)"
  ]
}
```

Here is the **Log output** I get in the AWS console:

```
the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install","stack":["Error: ","Something went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module","","Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'","Require stack:","- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js","- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js","- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js","- /var/task/index.js","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/Runtime.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","","Possible solutions:","- Install with verbose logging and look for errors: \"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --foreground-scripts --verbose sharp\"","- Install for the current linux-x64 runtime: \"npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp\"","- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js:34:9)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)","    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)","    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:8:1)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)"]}
2022-10-26T03:30:59.951Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"\nSomething went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module\n\nCannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/Runtime.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js\n\nPossible solutions:\n- Install with verbose logging and look for errors: \"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --foreground-scripts --verbose sharp\"\n- Install for the current linux-x64 runtime: \"npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp\"\n- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install","stack":["Error: ","Something went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module","","Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'","Require stack:","- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js","- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js","- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js","- /var/task/index.js","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/Runtime.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","","Possible solutions:","- Install with verbose logging and look for errors: \"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --foreground-scripts --verbose sharp\"","- Install for the current linux-x64 runtime: \"npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp\"","- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js:34:9)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)","    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)","    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:8:1)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)"]}
START RequestId: 0df51e26-e55f-42a0-8716-f2507ba7ff78 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 0df51e26-e55f-42a0-8716-f2507ba7ff78
REPORT RequestId: 0df51e26-e55f-42a0-8716-f2507ba7ff78  Duration: 2382.57 ms    Billed Duration: 2383 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 15 MB  
Unknown application error occurred
Error
```

Here is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "S3Triggeref35961b",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "sharp": "^0.31.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "amplify:S3Triggeref35961b": "cd amplify/backend/function/S3Triggeref35961b/src && npm install && rm -rf node_modules/sharp && SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1 npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --libc=glibc sharp && cd -"
  }
}
```

Here is my **index.js**:

```
const sharp = require("sharp");

exports.handler = async function (event) {
  console.log("Hello World!");
};
```